# Can Knockout components be registered by a dynamically generated <script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application, html5-history

The motive is that I don't want to register all my components when the website is first visited by the browser. I want to be able to register components when a code needs it, and I don't want the JS file of the component to be loaded when the web page loads the very first time. Via Ajax, I want to load JS files containing component registration code.

Please, is this possible in Knockout?

Comment: that seems possible through RequireJS..

Comment: I don't want to have the RequireJS configuration beforehand. I don't want to have any clue about the component until an <a> calls a URL that a JS function then uses to load view model and template for the concerned component whose name should be indicated by the caller <a> (e.g. in a data attribute or something). There would be another JS code to hijack the URL call using History API without in order to prevent page reloads.

Comment: There's a way to create custom component loader that can load, from URLs, view model data and template markup for a component. So, the question is about if I can call ko.components.register (using a JS code that has been supplied with a component name and the URLs for the view model and the template needed for the component) sometime later in code even long after the page has been loaded, so as to dynamically register component whose view model and template are loaded using a custom loader.

Comment: And how should ko.applyBindings be called? With or without parameters? Or would the newly loaded component simply start working?

Comment: The easy way out is to run the registration code for all my thousand components when a page loads, but then use them when needed. So, the question is still that how can I avoid having to register a thousand components but register them later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load components in a different way than provided by Knockout's default loader (which uses `ko.components.register`), you should create a custom loader ([docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html)). It seems that in your case, you'll just want to implement the `getConfig` method to return the configuration for a component.

Comment: Thank you. I had visited the docs on custom loaders. I am using the code examples in loading custom components that belong to the same category (e.g. partial views that supply the main content of a web page), which was the original problem that was hard for me to express in my question. I was able to use just one custom component name to load each and swap them. I didn't know you later responded. Thank you for being swift. I'll mark your answer as the answer and it is the foundation to build on. I've successfully started extended my code to do routing, etc. I'll share my progress later.

Comment: I have worked on the routing. I couldn't post it very much earlier so that I could take some time to verify that all the code work as expected. I am through and have now posted [a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204936/client-side-routing-using-knockout-and-html5-history-api-for-a-single-page-web-a) about it on coderreview. It is a full ASP.NET MVC 5 project that does client-side routing using Knockout and HTML5 History API and can easily be made to work with any server-side web development framework. Thank you in anticipation of your help over there.